# Dapper update query with multiple parameters of different type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dapper

I have just started using Dapper and I have the following code that produces a query based on a combination of parameters (a list and a local variable)

```
var sqlQuery = $"UPDATE MyItem SET ItemOrder = @ItemOrder WHERE Id = @Id AND TenantId = @TenantId;";

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@ItemOrder", myItems.Select(x=> x.ItemOrder));
parameters.Add("@Id", myItems.Select(x => x.Id));
parameters.Add("@TenantId", SessionInfo.TenantId);

await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(sqlQuery, parameters, transaction: transaction);
```

and I can see in SQL Server Profiler the following query that is executed

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE MyItem SET ItemOrder = (@ItemOrder1,@ItemOrder2,@ItemOrder3) WHERE Id = (@Id1,@Id2,@Id3) AND TenantId = @TenantId;',
N'@ItemOrder1 int,@ItemOrder2 int,@ItemOrder3 int,@Id1 bigint,@Id2 bigint,@Id3 bigint,@TenantId bigint',
@ItemOrder1=1,@ItemOrder2=2,@ItemOrder3=3,@Id1=1,@Id2=2,@Id3=5,@TenantId=1
```

which returns `Incorrect syntax near ','`

Why am I getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're setting list items `myItems.Select(x=> x.ItemOrder)`. Use `myItems.Select(x=> x.ItemOrder).FirstOrDefault()` and try

Comment: But I want to add all items in the myItems list not just the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
foreach(var item in myItems)
{
     var sqlQuery = $"UPDATE MyItem SET ItemOrder = @ItemOrder WHERE Id = @Id AND TenantId = @TenantId;";

     var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
     parameters.Add("@ItemOrder", item.ItemOrder);
     parameters.Add("@Id", item.Id);
     parameters.Add("@TenantId", SessionInfo.TenantId);

     await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(sqlQuery, parameters, transaction: transaction);
}
```

Comment: this will create multiple update queries on the server.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, you need to write SP with table parameters.

Comment: ok I just ran a test and passed a list as parameter. I saw that dapper on the background generates multiple update queries so I suppose your solution is accepted